# Casting a UserControl as a specific type of user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Is there a way to cast a user control as a specific user control so I have access to it's public properties? Basicly I'm foreaching through a placeholder's controls collection and I'm trying to access the user control's public properties.

```
foreach(UserControl uc in plhMediaBuys.Controls)
{
    uc.PulblicPropertyIWantAccessTo;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach(UserControl uc in plhMediaBuys.Controls) {
    MyControl c = uc as MyControl;
    if (c != null) {
        c.PublicPropertyIWantAccessTo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this way of doing it although fallen888's will work too.

Comment: In fact, this example seems less efficient to me, because you're creating another instance of MyControl.

Comment: This code doesn't actually create a new instance of MyControl, it just creates a new reference to one. References are essentially pointers, so there should be no performance penalty here.

Comment: Actually, if you use the "as" keyword or just cast the variable, you are doing the same thing. The only difference between the two is "as" returns null if it can't cast, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: I stand corrected, however it still seems unnecessary - adds onto the complexity of the code.

Comment: do I need some sort of using directive or an assembly reference in my code behind that refrences MyControl?

Comment: Perhaps it is more complex to someone unfamiliar with C#, but it also saves a cast (quasi-expensive).

Comment: Ouch, that's hurtful, SoloBold.  :)  I just meant it adds to code congestion.

Comment: I didn't mean you wouldn't be able to understand it fallen :)

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach(UserControl uc in plhMediaBuys.Controls)
{
  if (uc is MySpecificType)
  {
    return (uc as MySpecificType).PulblicPropertyIWantAccessTo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you use the "as" keyword or just cast the variable, you are doing the same thing. The only difference between the two is "as" returns null if it can't cast, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: True, but it'll never hit that line if it's not able to cast.

Answer (score 3):

### Casting

I prefer to use:

```
foreach(UserControl uc in plhMediaBuys.Controls)
{
    ParticularUCType myControl = uc as ParticularUCType;
    if (myControl != null)
    {
        // do stuff with myControl.PulblicPropertyIWantAccessTo;
    }
}
```

Mainly because using the is keyword causes two (quasi-expensive) casts:

```
if( uc is ParticularUCType ) // one cast to test if it is the type
{
    ParticularUCType myControl = (ParticularUCType)uc; // second cast
    ParticularUCType myControl = uc as ParticularUCType; // same deal this way
    // do stuff with myControl.PulblicPropertyIWantAccessTo;
}
```

### References

- [The 3 Cast Operators in C#](http://rusek.org/stefan/default.aspx/2008/10/22/the-3-cast-operators-in-c/73/)
- [Type Casting Impact over Execution Performance in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcasts.aspx)