# Get UserControl from inside ControlCollection

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

So i am currently adding a collection of usercontrols to a Panel Collection.

Here is that code

```
foreach (IssuePoll poll in issuePollList)
{
     IssuePollsUC issuePoll = (IssuePollsUC)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/IssuePollsUC.ascx");
     issuePoll.LoadPoll(poll, false, politician.PoliticianID);
     pnlUnFinishedTest.Controls.Add(issuePoll);
}
```

I am trying to get those usercontrols so i can call a validate method and save method inside each of those controls.  Here is the code i am using for that, but it is not working.

```
foreach (Control control in pnlUnFinishedTest.Controls)
{
     IssuePollsUC issuePolls = (IssuePollsUC)control;
     issuePolls.SavePollAnswer(appUser.User.PersonID);
}
```

I get an error message on the convert, it says

*"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'UserControls.IssuePollsUC'"*

EDIT:  Looks like the problem lies in the fact that a Control cannot be convert into (User Control)

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Its not finding the controls?

Comment: I get an error message on the convert, it says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'UserControls.IssuePollsUC'"

Answer (score 0):

There are other controls in your panel other than your user control i.e. the literal that is causing the cast to fail. Try

```
foreach (Control control in pnlUnFinishedTest.Controls) 
{    
     IssuePollsUC issuePolls = control as IssuePollsUC;      

     if(issuePolls != null)
     {
          issuePolls.SavePollAnswer(appUser.User.PersonID); 
     } 
}
```

This will make it more type safe.

**EDIT**

Please note that you must add dynamic controls in the `Page_Init` event not `Page_Load` or anywhere else. I suspect your controls aren't even there - adding them not in `Page_Init` means that that they are not in `ViewState` and won't be present in any control collection.

Comment: I have tried using that method you tried above and it gives me the same results.  On using Page_Init, the controls is actually loaded and visible on the page loading it in the page_load.  So the control is there, and the panel has one object in it's controls collection (it should be the only object in there anyways).

Comment: @AndyXufuris. I'm a bit unclear. Are you still getting the exception then? If so on what line of code. The as keyword shoul dprevent the exception being thrown. This SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227121/casting-a-usercontrol-as-a-specific-type-of-user-control is doing exacrly what you want with the change in the freach i.e. foreach(UserControl uc in plhMediaBuys.Controls).  Does that help?