# dynamically creating online survey/test

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am looking to create a page to test/survey a user.  I will be creating the questions and answers choices form an admin page which saves to the database.  I am needing to figure out how to dynamically create the page to display these and be able to get the information out when saving.

This is what i have been trying to add all the information into.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPollText" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblPollChoices" Visible="false" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPollChoices" Visible="false" runat="server">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

My biggest problem is getting the information back in a usefull manner so i can save each response.  I tried adding the code above to a userpanel and recursively adding panels passing the questionid in to load it.  My big problem there was getting the information back after the user clicked save.  I brought that question up here with no luck [Get UserControl from inside ControlCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932843/get-usercontrol-from-inside-controlcollection)

I've tried searching google for a good way to do this, but have yet found one.  The best i found was using xml which i don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did the same thing using asp.net MVC.. thats easier.. but still u can do this using simple asp.net 
one way for u is to create forms using jquery on the client side which is the next easiest approach i can think of when the user submits forms then u can get all the information in 
`Request.Form` Collection 
now because it feels like you have already made the Q&A form and want to get the values back. 
because the controls you hav made are dynamically generated based on the underlying form structure you will have to create the controls on every `Page_Load()` event.
then you will be able to access teh values.
if your dynamic controls are in some container control you will still have to generate them and then look them in the `ContainerControl.Controls` property you will find them there.
or u can override everything and here also lok in `request.form` collection and parse it to get the values

Answer (score 0):

I am doing kinda same project. In my case I have a ViewModel that contains object of Question and list of Answers.I use javascript to extend the list of Answers while creating Question and Answer and then insert them into database. Once my ViewModel is populated I can access the information using again ViewModel object and display it. After you have a proper display of it you can easily get what the user picked for an answer. To insert the answer of the user you will need another table in database that saves the users choice. Hopefully you get the idea how to do it.